# Using dateadd with specific conditions

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have two different date fields in my report. One is command.install date and the other is command.mfgdate. My problem is for some records mfgdate is blank and others installdate is blank and sometimes both dates exist in a record. I’m trying to use a formula with dateadd to return a replacement date based on a predetermined number of years. What I would like to do is use a formula that would first use mfgdate then use installdate as a “safety net” if mfgdate happens to be blank. Is there anyway that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If a date shows "blank" inside the report, it usually means the date is `NULL`.

Therefore, the following formula should give you the desired result:

```
If Not IsNull({command.mfgdate}) Then
    {command.mfgdate}
Else If Not IsNull({command.installdate}) Then
    {command.installdate}
Else
    // backup-date if both dates are NULL
    CDate(1900,1,1)
```